# send_mail not working in django

Tags: django

I wrote this code
**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailhere@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemailhere@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**views.py**

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email ['myemailhere@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'how are you?', to=['myemailhere@gmail.com'])
    email.send()
    send_mail('Test mail', 'This is a test', 'myemailhere@gmail.com' ['myemailhere@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

In success(request), I added a bit of redundant code to try sending mail in a different way just to check if other method is working or not. None of it is working. Can anyone please tell me why? I am a bit confused. Password is correct and i allowed less secured apps for gmail.This program is not throwing any error. Success page is called if email(request) tells that it has sent mail successfully. I am using django 1.11 and Python 2.7
Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: what happend when you [unlock the captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console backend doesn't send real emails:

> Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the console backend writes to stdout.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#console-backend

Depending on how you've set up logging, the emails sent with `send_mail` should be somewhere in your log files (or not, if you're not logging stdout).

You would have to modify your settings.py like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that it should have been smtp instead of email. Thanks a tons

Answer (score 0):

When you pass values to your `send_mail` function you forget to put a comma, first after `from_email`:

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['myemailhere@gmail.com'])
```

and second after `'myemailhere@gmail.com'`

```
send_mail('Test mail', 'This is a test', 'myemailhere@gmail.com', ['myemailhere@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Also you have to remove the line `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` from your **settings.py** file.